# How to run Scala app as system user with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am making an app using sbt. I want to store some files in /var/lib/$appname. I have already created the system group and system user:

`groupadd -r $appname`

`useradd -M -r --home /var/lib/$appname --shell /sbin/nologin --gid $appname $appname`

Now I need my code to run as that user, but I'm not sure how. I executed `whoami` in my app, and saw it was running as my login user.

How do I configure sbt to run the app as this system user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to do it. One way is to use the [sbt-native-packager](https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/index.html) plugin to generate a package for your distribution and then install it using your distribution's package manager. You can use the “Java Server Application” archetype and the [daemonUser](https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/archetypes/java_server/index.html#settings-tasks) setting to configure the user. sbt-native-packager will also integrate with your init system by generating systemd or upstart configuration files and/or an init script.